# Belt and pulley fell off 40" attic fan & my repair failed (updated)

Tags: exhaust-fan

Summary (also see photos of fan and motor below)

Update 2:

I bought a capacitor for small dollars and now the fan works again, perfectly.

Update 1: Capacitor was indeed broken (see photo at end)

1. Belt and upper pulley fell off 40" attic fan
2. Attic fan motor turns when not connected to anything
3. Fan blades turn easily by hand
4. When I put the pulley and belt together the motor does not turn the fan at all.

   What should I try?

Here are some more details.

My large (40" diameter) attic fan has worked flawlessly for years, on a thermostat.  Recently we have not heard it.

I climbed into the low ceiling attic and found the 18" belt on the floor and the 7" top pulley on the floor as well.

The motor turned when the I manually triggered thermostat.

I put the pulley back on the shaft and tightened it in place with the set screw. Then I put the belt back on the pulleys and triggered the thermostat.  I replaced the belt with my bare hands, so it cannot be very tight.

Surprise: the motor tries to turn (jerks in place) but does not turn.

The fan blade itself is easy to turn by hand.

Why did the pulley fall off and what should I try now to get it running again?

If you need any more info, tell me what you need.

Thanks.
[image: Fan]

[image: Motor]

[image: Capacitor]

Comment: Idle thought -- what's the tension on the belt look like?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  I replaced the belt with my bare hands, so it cannot be very tight.

Comment: Is the belt slipping by chance? What type of motor is turning it?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel The belt is not slipping.  The motor shaft jerks just a little and then stops moving.  If I take off the belt, the motor sins happily.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel. It is a little 110 v motor.  It turns fast with no load.  I can try to take a picture of the label on the motor.

Comment: Please get us a picture of the motor label

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel. I added a photo of the motor panel to the question.

Comment: Looks like the capacitor my have a leak, is that possible? In the pic there is a spot on the plywood directly below the capacitor

Comment: @Jack. The capacitor is surely broken (see photo at end of question). The can is broken open, so likely the fluid did cause the discoloring on the floor!  
Now, let me ask, is the capacitor polarized?  I do not see any indication of polarization on the old capacitor and the two wires leading to it are the same color.

Comment: That's a good one for ThreePhaseEel to answer. My guess is if the wires are not different colors as in both black then it should not matter but if they are colored then it will. That is only my educated guess though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Check the capacitor

Since the motor starts and runs no-load, it's not the motor windings themselves, and the capacitor isn't *open* or *shorted* most likely.  I'd check it anyway though, as it's likely way out of spec, which'd explain the behavior you're seeing (starts unloaded, but fails to start up under load) and the motor is a Permanent Split Capacitor (PSC) type, so there's no start switch involved here.

Comment: How do I check the capacitor?  Is it easy to just get a new one and swap it in?  Is it that can type thing in the photo of the motor?  Should I find specs on the old one?

Comment: It is indeed the can in the photo of the motor -- there will be printing on it giving the value and voltage rating (the motor catalog says to use a 10M/370V cap which I suspect means 10&micro;F/370V), and yes it's fairly easy to swap for that matter

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Just a thought, still possibly "a single" winding? With No load it could have enough to get it started. (would expect ti to spin erratically). The CAP is pretty common too.

Comment: @noybman -- yeah, a good start and a bad run winding *could* cause this, I'd be more inclined to suspect the cap though

Comment: I wonder if that strangely colored patch on the floor directly beneath the capacitor is a result of leaked electrolyte ...

Comment: The capacitor is surely broken (see photo at end of question). Thanks!
Now, let me ask, is the capacitor polarized?  I do not see any indication of polarization on the old capacitor and the two wires leading to it are the same color.

Comment: @brhans. Good observation. The can is broken open, so likely the fluid did cause the discoloring on the floor.

Comment: Also, why would a failed capacitor cause the 7" pulley to fall off? (I found the pulley on the floor of the attic.)

Comment: @Yehuda_NYC -- the capacitor is not polarized (it can't be since it has AC on both sides of it).  Dunno how the capacitor failure and the pulley problem are related, though...maybe the motor failure caused the pulley to shake loose?

Comment: I put in replacement capacitor and now the fan works again. Thank you!